# How do you make Empties visible in final renders

Tags: rendering, empty

I can't see the images I imported into blender in the final render.

Comment: You can't render an empty, you should have imported the image as "Images as Planes", or go into View > Viewport Render Image

Answer (score 2):

If you add the image as a *Reference* or *Background*, it won't show up in the render. Instead, you should add it as a texture to a plane. There is an add-on called *Import Images as Planes* that simplifies this.

[image: Add-on]

Once it is enabled, its operator will show up (*Add > Image > Images as Planes*). When you run it, it will open a file browser to allow you to select the image file you want to use. More importantly, you should tweak the operator settings. The most important are the *Material Settings* which will determine how the plane will behave in the render.

[image: Operator]

[image: Operator Settings]

Comment: Thank you. That helped

Comment: You're welcome!